# Define entry price based on condition

Tags: pine-script

I'm having trouble setting the entry price for my *position*. For example how do I setup a limit price so that it's *equal* to a moving average? *(If this condition happens place limit order at this price)*

```
longCondition1 = ...
if (longCondition1)
    strategy.entry()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strategy.entry(... , limit = sma(close, 15))`

Answer (score 0):

If `longCondition1` is true, the strategy will place an entry with an ID "Long_ID". We use `strategy.long` in the perimeter to specify it as a long entry. In order to include a limit price of the order, we specify it with `limit = sma(close, 15)`.

```
longCondition1 = ...
if (longCondition1)
    strategy.entry("Long_ID", strategy.long, limit = sma(close, 15))
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how this answer will solve the problem, instead of posting code-only answer.